# Code selector using inheritage during runtime

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there a way to insert an abstract class inside a container? No.
Is there a way for a base class to access derived classes? Using virtual functions.
Is there a way for this example code to work properly and the console to *bark*?
Is there a way for the `vector` container to keep the instances and not references/pointers?

Storing pointers inside the `std::vector` will only be safe if I use reference counters to the instances, which is my last resort. Do I miss something?

```
class CAnimal
{
public:
    virtual void soundsLike()
    {
        cout<<"Base function\n";
    }   
};

class CDog: public CAnimal
{
public:
    void soundsLike()
    {
        cout<<"Woof\n";
    }
};

class CZoo
{
public:
    std::vector<CAnimal> animalList;

    void addDog()
    {
        animalList.push_back(CDog());
    }

};
```

Console outputs the base function message:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CZoo nationalPark;
    nationalPark.addDog();
    nationalPark.animalList.front().soundsLike(); //Calls the base function.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to insert an abstract class inside a container? No." => Not directly, but you totally can with a pointer.

Comment: "Is there a way to insert an abstract class inside a container? No." Why you ask a question in 1st sentence, and answer it in 2nd? xD

Comment: @JBL Using a container with pointers produces an access violation. Destructor of CDog is called as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<CAnimal> > zoo;
zoo.push_back(new CDog());
zoo[0]->soundsLike();
```

Is it bad? unique_ptr will handle the destruction for you.

I don't think you can use references. Also I don't think you can make it "bark" currently. Only "woof".

Comment: All answers were great but yours was very straightforward. I used cv::Ptr smart pointer class because I already include opencv in my projects and I also don't use C++11 (yet).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to insert an abstract class inside a container?

No. But you can insert a pointer to an abstract class (preferably, a smart pointer)

> Is there a way for this example code to work properly and the console to bark?

Not unless you are willing to go with a pointer: otherwise, the barking code [would be sliced off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

> Is there a way for the vector container to keep the instances and not references/pointers?

You can keep pointers in a container, but you cannot keep references. However, once you have a pointer in your class to an object that you allocate, or a whole vector of pointers, the complexity of your code goes up, because you must follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

> Storing pointers inside the `std::vector` will only be safe if I use reference counters to the instances, which is my last resort. Do I miss something?

Yes - it appears that you are missing [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), which does reference counting for you. The small price that you pay for that is having to use `std::shared_ptr` in place of a simple pointer for all animals in `CZoo`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to skip storing pointers in your containers, here is a solution implementing the "fake virtual" mechanism. Please note that this will work only if you have the luxury of a C++11 compiler. You will need to call the virtual methods via a helper function (`caller`), and use a method (`makeNoice` for our case) which acts as being virtual to channel all virtual calls via the mechanism.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

// forward declarations of the base class and a helper function
class CAnimal;
void caller(CAnimal* a);

// base class with small extensions
struct CAnimal {
    CAnimal() {  mf = std::bind(caller, this); }
    virtual void soundsLike() { std::cout<<"Base function\n"; }

    // this will act as a virtual function
    void makeNoice() { mf(this); }
    std::function<void (CAnimal*)> mf;
};

// a helper function to call the real virtual function
void caller(CAnimal* a) {a->soundsLike();}

// the actual animals
struct CDog: public CAnimal {
    virtual void soundsLike() { std::cout<<"Woof\n"; }
};
struct CCat: public CAnimal {
    virtual void soundsLike() { std::cout<<"Miau\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    CDog dog; 
    CCat cat;

    std::vector<CAnimal> animalList;
    animalList.push_back(dog);
    animalList.push_back(cat);

    // calling the fake virtual
    animalList[0].makeNoice();
    animalList[1].makeNoice();
}
```

And here is it on ideone: http://ideone.com/MRDaZ3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that animalList is just a vector of your base class CAnimal objects. So your compiler is only keeping enough storage to hold CAnimal objects. Due to the way virtual functions work, your derived CDog class will always require more storage than a CAnimal class because of the lookup table requirement.

Since your CDog class does not have enough storage allocated, the CDog part of the object is getting sliced off and only the CAnimal part of the object remains.

Using pointers to pass objects around is preferential because the address of an object always has the same storage requirement so you won't run into any object slicing issues.