# Avoiding object slicing in a method call

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I've been trying to rewrite a program of mine to allow for inherited classes. I'm running into a problem with slicing. I originally had `Parent m_parent` in my `Test` class (therefore no dynamic allocation in Test), but added that thinking it'd fix my issue, but it hasn't. I don't know if I'm making my issue worse or if it's as simple as writing a copy constructor (or some other simple fix).

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        Parent();
    private:
        string a;
};
class Child : public Parent
{
     private:
        string b;
};
class Test
{
     public:
        Test()
        {
            m_parent = new Parent;
        }
        void testFunction(Parent &parent)
        {
            *m_parent = parent;
        }
        ~Test()
        {
             delete m_parent;
        }
     private:
        Parent * m_parent;
};
```

Doing something like this still causes slicing...

```
Child c("foo", "bar");
Parent * p = &c;
Test.testFunction(*p);
```

Comment: So you want to copy an arbitrarily derived instance of Parent?

Comment: Reminds me of an [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220589/code-selector-using-inheritage-during-runtime) I have. I use smart pointers since. Use [C++11](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus-Smart-Pointers) or [boost](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8394/Smart-Pointers-to-boost-your-code).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. this line:

```
*m_parent = parent;
```

causes the object to be sliced into `Parent` object regardless on what it really is.

Other than that, there are many error proned lines of code in your example, but I guess its only because it's a very specific question.

**Edit:**
A suggestion how to avoid slicing:

```
template <class T>
void testFunction(T& t){
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Parent,T>::value,"only subclasses of Parent may be passed to testFunction");
     delete m_parent;
     m_parent = new T(t); //or: new T(std::move(t));
}
```

***EDIT 2:***
this shall work if you pass a child object as real object and not as a parent pointer , AKA `testFunction(myChild)`

***EDIT3:*** @Jarod42 has a good point about the `clone` method. the two of the solution can be used together

Comment: How can I avoid this though? I have multiple derived objects that I need to work for methods where `Parent` objects are passed in (this being an example).

Comment: @i4h apart from the fact that the code is not even compiling because the constructors have no body, the Child constructor is not accepting parameters and that `Test.testfunction` is not a static method, one of the big issues is that the implementation of `Test` is leaking memory because calling the `testFunction` will lose the `m_parent` that the constructor created. And after that the `Test` destructor will attempt to clean up memory that it is not allowed to touch or worse, as `m_parent` is referencing an object on the stack that was probably already destructed by that point.

Comment: @CompuChip Sorry that I didn't put a body for the constructor. I only put that there to show that it exists. Also, I've checked for memory leaks in my program, but don't have any. I don't quite see why it would cause memory leaks (not saying you'er wrong).

Comment: Deleting null pointer is safe, so `if (m_parent)` is unneeded.

Comment: Your function take the static type, and not the dynamic type, So with OP's example `Parent * p = &c;
Test.testFunction(*p);` `T` is `Parent`, not `Child`...

Answer (score 2):

There are no object slicings, but `m_parent` doesn't become a `Child` and only `string a` is copied.

If you want keep a copy in `Test`, I suggest using `Clone`:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual Parent* Clone() const { return new Parent(*this); }
private:
    string a;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child* Clone() const override { return new Child(*this); }
private:
    string b;
};

class Test
{
public:
    void testFunction(const Parent &parent)
    {
        m_parent.reset(parent.Clone());
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> m_parent;
};
```

Comment: Excellent solution: this shold be the way to go ! But I wonder about "no object slicing" : I think in OP's code there's a potential slicing issue with `*m_parent=parent;`, due to reference wich could refer to a child. In OP's example though, calling the function with a dereferenced parent pointer to make a reference, I'm not sure if the slicing occurs already before the call or in the assignment...

Comment: @Christophe: I wouldn't say that `*m_parent=parent` is object slicing, it uses `Parent::operator =(const Parent&)` which copy `Parent` part.